# Is particular type exception catching faster than general type exception catching?If faster which ratio?

Tags: java, exception

I want to know particular exception like `NullPointerException` ex is faster than `Exception` ex.

For example my code throws `NullPointerException`

```
try {
   ...
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
   ...
}
```

or

```
try {
   ...
} catch (Exception e) {
   ...
}
```

Which one is faster? I think exception system depends on flags so particular type is faster because of less control. But I wonder.

And if the answer is yes say why? Thanks.

Not: You suppose there isn't any crashes on code.

Comment: Which language/compiler are we talking about here?

Comment: @Owen S. Looks like Java

Comment: @dpb: Either that or poorly written C++, just wanted to make sure. :-) @Judas: of course it does!

Answer (score 1):

The usual caveats apply... Make sure you don't [optimize prematurely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature).  Program for clarity instead of speed.  If the program is too slow, use a profiler to find the problem.

Supposing Java and no exceptions are thrown, they are equally fast.  The [athrow](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/Instructions2.doc.html#athrow) operation is never called so no lookups will be performed on the exception tables and no exception-class matching needs to be done.

If you throw an exception in a try statement with a single, specific exception handler that will match the exception then the exception table lookup will match the specific exception class **marginally** faster than the general Exception class because it won't climb up the class hierarchy to find the matching ancestor class.  By marginally, I mean you should save fewer than 10 CPU instructions and thrown exceptions should be exceptionally rare.

If you throw a variety of exceptions and have multiple catch blocks, the situation is too complicated to say it would be faster or slower to catch a single, common ancestor-class like exception; it depends on the details.

The function findExceptionBlockInMethod in [Kaffe's exception.c](http://www.kaffe.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/kaffe/kaffe/kaffevm/exception.c?rev=1.111) shows one implementation of the exception-matching code.