# how to get a back buffer copy inside the video memory?

Tags: directx, direct3d, directx-9

Now I can get backbuffer pointer called pBackBuffer by

```
m_pDevice->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, 
    IREF_GETPPTR(pBackBuffer,IDirect3DSurface9));
```

And then create a surface called pSurfTemp in syetem memory by

```
m_pDevice->CreateOffscreenPlainSurface(
    g_Proc.m_Stats.m_SizeWnd.cx, g_Proc.m_Stats.m_SizeWnd.cy, 
    s_bbFormat, D3DPOOL_SYSTEMMEM, 
    IREF_GETPPTR(pSurfTemp,IDirect3DSurface9), NULL );
```

Then I get the back buffer data by

```
m_pDevice->GetRenderTargetData(pBackBuffer, pSurfTemp);
```

Data seems transforming like this:  videoMemory->systemMemory

Since next step is to operate the data in video memory again, it will copy it from system memory back into video memory. It wastes time.

I want to copy the data inside video memory, How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you will want to [`CreateOffscreenPlainSurface()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174358%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`D3DPOOL_DEFAULT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) flag, so driver will choose appropriate memory location automatically. But it never guaranteed that it always will be videocard's on-board memory.

By the way, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature). =)

**Edit:** Another option is to switch API from DirectX 9 (which is obsolete) to DirectX 11, which allows much more precise resources manipulations. Also, OpenGL goes somewhere in between. Both, is a huge code rewrite.

Comment: Yeah...I have tried it. Since [GetRenderTargetData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174405(v=vs.85).aspx) can not take a Surface created with [D3DPOOL_DEFAULT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), I used LoadSurfaceFromSurface instead. But it was even Slower. Dont know why.