# Is it necessary to to end a php query or function width ';' in html tags?

Tags: php

I have simple question. I'm learning php and I realized that to end a function with ';' is not necesscary if any other function or query doesn't exists. But I wonder, while using php in html tags as in the example, not to end functions can cause any performance and security problems ?

```
<?php foreach( $cars as $car ):?>
  <option><?php echo $car ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: try it yourself and you'll get the answer!!!! :)

Comment: Write the ; ! It will be always good.

Comment: My eyes would bleed for days if I ever had to inherit your project. Just use the `;` please

Comment: Your terminology is a little confused - what you have above are not functions, but rather flow control statements. Anyway, PHP will insert an implicit ; when it encounters a ?>. It is not advisable to get into the habit of omitting ; however.

Comment: Check documentation / my answer for a "to-the-source" explanation.

Comment: Thank u Lyth, now I'm reading documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as PHP is concerned, there is absolutely no difference at all between these two blocks of code. It inserts the trailing semi-colon automatically if it's missing before a `?>`.

The only difference is for the developer. **Best practice is to always include the semi-colon.** The reason for this is not because of anything different in PHP, but because it makes the code easier to work with for a developer.

For the same reason that it's best practice to always put `{}` braces around a block, even if it's only one line (where the braces aren't strictly required). Because it makes your code easier to work with.

So, to summarise:

- Difference between `<?php echo $car ?>` and `<?php echo $car; ?>`:
  **None**. PHP sees them as identical.
- Security issues:
  **None**. See above. (it's good to worry about security, but you need to get to know what the real security dangers are rather than guessing)
- Performance issues:
  **None**. See above. (however, I wouldn't worry about it anyway; you're in danger of falling victim to [premature optimisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature)).
- So why include the semicolon?
  Because it makes your life easier as a coder.

Answer (score 4):

In php, while ending the php code with `?>`, there is no need to give ; or you may give. This is optional, and it will not cause any performance and security problems. But as a good practice you should not leave the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary for any one line of code to have semicolons now. It will not cause any performance or security problems either.

For more information on what the standards are, please take a look at FIG (Framework Interop Group) models PSR-1 and PSR-2 here: [github.com/php-fig/fig-standards](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/tree/master/accepted)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, no you dont have to use the `;` after your `endofreach` in this situation.

*However consider this!*

When you come to add some new code to this script lets say 6 months later and you forget to check back in the code to see if you now need to add a semicolon on that foreach, you will get problems with the script, that have nothing to do with your new code, but that will be where you look because thats all you have changed!!

If you **ALWAYS** add the closing semi colon terminator, this will never be a problem.

*Code with the future in mind.*

Comment: Your answer is different from the others, I will think about it

Answer (score 0):

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php) says :

> The closing tag of a block of PHP code automatically implies a
>   semicolon; 
>       you do not need to have a semicolon terminating the last line of a PHP block.

That's why you don't need your semicolon for your `echo` in this particular case.