# Efficiency: For x in EmptyList vs if length > 0

Tags: python, performance, list, empty-list

Sorry, kind of a hard question to title.

If I want to iterate over a potentially empty list, which is more efficient? I'm expecting the list to be empty the majority of the time.

```
for x in list: 
    dostuff()
```

OR

```
if len(list)>0:
     for x in list:
        dostuff()
```

Comment: No offense, but this kind of question is among the least productive ones that one can possibly ask. Not only is it astonishingly unlikely that any performance difference actually matters in the slightest, if it did you should be addressing this by **benchmarking** instead of asking or guessing. *Reasoning* about performance doesn't even work very well when looking at C code and knowing the entire stack of hardware and software involved. It works even worse when looking at Python code and not knowing much about hardware and the Python implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on timings from the `timeit` module:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('for x in lst:pass', 'lst=[]')
0.08301091194152832
>>> timeit('if len(lst)>0:\n  for x in lst:\n    pass', 'lst=[]')
0.09223318099975586
```

It looks like just doing the `for` loop will be faster when the list is empty, making it faster option regardless of the state of the list.

However, there is a significantly faster option:

```
>>> timeit('if lst:\n  for x in lst:\n    pass', 'lst=[]')
0.03235578536987305
```

Using `if lst` is much faster than either checking the length of the list or always doing the `for` loop. However, all three methods are quite fast, so if you are trying to optimize your code I would suggest trying to find what the real bottleneck is - take a look at [When is optimisation premature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `if list:`

```
In [15]: if l:
   ....:     print "hello"
   ....:     

In [16]: l1= [1]

In [17]: if l1:
   ....:     print "hello from l1"
   ....:     
hello from l1

In [21]: %timeit for x in l:pass
10000000 loops, best of 3: 54.4 ns per loop

In [22]: %timeit if l:pass
10000000 loops, best of 3: 22.4 ns per loop
```

If a list is empty `if list` will evaluate to `False` so no need to check the `len(list)`.

Comment: I don't think that answers the question

Comment: @TimCastelijns If the list is normally empty using `if list` will be faster

Answer (score 1):

Firstly `if len(list) > 0:` should be `if list:` to improve readability. I personally would have thought having the `if` statement is redundant but `timeit` seems to prove me wrong. It seems (unless I've made a silly mistake) that having the check for an empty list makes the code faster (for an empty list):

```
$ python -m timeit 'list = []' 'for x in list:' '    print x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.157 usec per loop

$ python -m timeit 'list = []' 'if list:' '    for x in list:' '        print x'
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0766 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

First variant is more efficient, because Python's for loop checks length of list anyway, making additional explicit check just a waste of CPU cycles.

Comment: Talk is cheap. Benchmarks is where it's at! (Also, you neglect the possibility that setting up a loop and stepping into the list methods takes longer than a Python-level length check.)

Comment: According to timeit, there is no difference at all, i.e. one could be sometimes faster, sometimes slower. First one shows 0.003286123275756836 and second shows 0.0032868385314941406 over 10000 loops.