# jQuery("#id") or jQuery(document.getElementById("id"))?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The performance difference is shown [here](http://jsperf.com/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery-selector).

Should I use `jQuery("#id")` or `jQuery(document.getElementById("id"))`?

Should I change all of my uses of `jQuery("#id")` to `document.getElementById("id")` because of the performance difference?

I prefer `jQuery("#id")` because it is easier to read and consistent with the CSS selector.

Comment: You should perform profiling on your web page to determine whether changing the selectors improve the performance significantly.

Comment: And `#id` is easier to read?!? I guess everyone has their own opinion.

Comment: ["premature optimization is the root of evil".](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature)

Comment: I use `$(document.getElementById(id))` when the `id` has characters that make the CSS id selector invalid, like `item#2` or `item.2`. Other than that, performance should be the last thing on your mind when using a convenience library like jQuery. Even then, I doubt this is the slowest part of your code.

Comment: In jQuery, to get the same result as document.getElementById, you can access the jQuery Object and get the first element in the object (Remember JavaScript objects act similar to associative arrays).

Comment: @Blender Do you just do that for readability? jQuery has the double-backslash (\\\) escape sequence for situations like that; see their [section on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Their example...an element with id="foo.bar", can use the selector $("#foo\\.bar").

Comment: @undefined, you might right. In term of performance, it might not make much difference at all in one page.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 . It make not much difference(*almost zero). Our team got mixture use of #id and document.getElementById. I am thinking to make it consistent and stop the argument.

Comment: Check jsperf http://jsperf.com/document-getelementbyid-vs-jquery/3

Comment: @bipsa, I am comparing $("#id") vs $(document.getElementById("")) not $("#id") vs document.getElementById

Comment: That test is also included in the jsperf link provided. My opinion is always to prefer performance over readability or ease of writing.

Comment: @nbrooks: But why do that when you can just forget about escaping it and drop it into `document.getElementById`?

Comment: @bipsa: Why are you using jQuery in the first place? Surely any sort of abstraction will just slow your code down?

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you, honestly.

A subjective question like this is going to get you a subjective answer, or, at best, a well thought-out list of pros and cons for each with a recommendation at the end.

I'll tell you this, though: using `$(#id)` saves you **a lot** of time if you're going to use it over and over again: look at the difference between the amount of characters in that and in `$(document.getElementById(id))`.

**Don't** use jQuery *solely* for this purpose, but if you're already using it and you're going to be referring to objects for DOM manipulation a lot, you might as well go the way that saves you some typing.

Comment: I think not only save times in coding. But saves time to argue with other programmer.

Comment: @hutingung Well, yes: that's very true.

Comment: I actually means jQuery(document.getElementById("id")) rather than document.getElementById("id");. You changed the meaning of the question.

Comment: @hutingung I see what you mean now: I wasn't sure which you were trying to refer to because you didn't close your parentheses, so it looked like a typo. My answer is the same, though.

Comment: @hutingung While you're right that I changed one aspect of the question, I didn't change *the meaning*. You're still asking the same thing, regardless, and all of the answers still apply. Wrapping `document.getElementById` in `jQuery()` just gives you access to jQuery's methods.

Comment: yes. I agreed with you. But I think @undefined comment is more concrete. And with that I think I will stick to $("#id") and make it consistent across the project.

Comment: @hutingung That would be my preference, as well. In fact, now that you say you're using jQuery either way, that's an even better choice.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, that is because of DOM abstraction, However all the current browsers, even IE6 respects `document.getElementById()`. Yes `document.getElementById()` is faster than $.('#id');