# implicit assignment operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

If I have an operator overload on my class, is the assignment version of the operator implicitly created as well?

```
class square{
   square operator+(const square& B);
   void operator=(const square& B);
};
```

As in, can I then call

```
square A, B;
A += B;
```

with the compiler implicitly deciding to call `operator+` then `operator=`?

Comment: Operator overloading is one of the best ways of making code unreadable. According to the [Google C++ Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.html#Operator_Overloading): "In general, do not overload operators. You can define ordinary functions like Equals() if you need them."

Comment: It is so much nicer though, when creating classes that are to be used to represent numbers to be able to read the code in a familiar format, it is a matter of;   A = A.add(B).div(C).mul(D)  vs  A = (A + B) / C * D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the operators aren't implicitly defined. However, [`boost/operators.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) defines useful helper templates to avoid boiler-plate code. Example from their docs :

> If, for example, you declare a class like this:

```
class MyInt
    : boost::operators<MyInt> {
    bool operator<(const MyInt& x) const;
    bool operator==(const MyInt& x) const;
    MyInt& operator+=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator-=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator*=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator/=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator%=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator|=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator&=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator^=(const MyInt& x);
    MyInt& operator++();
    MyInt& operator--(); };
```

> then the `operators<>` template adds more than a dozen additional operators, such as `operator>`, `<=`, `>=`, and
>   (binary) `+`. Two-argument forms of the templates are also provided to
>   allow interaction with other types.

In addition, there is also support for implicitly "deducing" just a specific set of operators using [arithmetic operator templates](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/utility/operators.htm#arithmetic).

Answer (score 5):

No, `+=` must be defined explicitly.

---

As a side note, `operator+` [should usually create a new object](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic):

```
square operator+(const square& B);
```

And `operator=` [should return a reference to `*this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment):

```
square& operator=(const square& B);
```

Also worth noting that `operator+` is usually implemented in terms of `operator+=`, i.e. `operator+` calls `operator+=` on the new copy.

Comment: as it does in all my implimentations, but i leave operator= void usually, as i have never used a multiple assignment

Comment: also, that refrence was not supposed to be there

Comment: Even though you have not used it *so far*, it doesn't hurt to have it there. The compiler will optimize it away where you aren't using it.

Comment: That is very good to know! My concern really was about the cost of moving data even when I would never use it, thank you!

Comment: @user4578093 Don't concern yourself with stuff like that, remember that ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/385529/3425536).

Comment: I thought that role was filled by money, but maybe money and premature optimization have a root network or something

Comment: That too. Both very evil.

Answer (score 3):

No `operator+=` is its own operator and must be defined explicitly.

Note that `operator+` should return a new object rather than a reference to the original object. The original object should be left unchanged.

`operator+=` should return the original object with the required value added. `operator+=` is often preferable as it eliminates a temporary object.