# Sorting an array in which multiple succeeding index number form one entry which should stay together

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array of over 1 million in length in which 3 succeeding indexes are 1 data-entry. The data-set would look something like this where `2.0` and `1.0` are the starting point of a data-entry the array:

```
double[] dataEntries = {2.0, 2.2, 2.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.1, ...};
```

Now I want to sort them but I have to keep them as entries together. I thought about swapping places like `bubble-sort`, but that has as complexity of `O(n^2)`. I also thought about `Array.sort()` but this does only works with an array without grouped indexes. I could use `%3` and get all the starting points of each data-set, then apply `Array.sort()` on this, but I have no idea if I am guaranteed to build back the relations correctly if I were to try to build back the relationships of the 3 succeeding indexes afterwards.

The result of the sorted `dataEntries` above:

```
sortedDataEntries = {1.0, 1.2, 1.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.1, ...};
```

I hope someone knows a good way to do this.

Comment: I see no difference between your input and the expected ouput. Please provide more samples.

Comment: Why don't you create a object to store your entry?

Comment: @Tichodroma fixed it to the correct way I wanted to demonstrate it.

Comment: @chengpohi I have all the data in one array for read-in and writeback efficiency purposes. Although I feel like there could be other ways I could have had the data at this point, I really want to only focus on this step and sort these multiple succeeding index numbers. I am trying to avoid objects.

Comment: How long is 'very long'?

Comment: @Tichodroma I agree that that is too vague, I will change that. The array's length is about 1 million. For the speed that is required and storage that is available that is very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with complexity `O(n*log(n))`.

I just take each third element into new array and when sorting it, I remember the position it had. Then based on changed position of grouped array I compose a new one. You can see that in last method "merge" I only need position array and the original array, the "grouped" one is no longer needed.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class JavaApplication39 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] dataEntries = {2.0, 2.2, 2.1, 1.0, 1.2, 1.1, 7.0,7.1,7.5};
        double[] dataGrouped = new double[dataEntries.length/3];
        int[] positions = new int[dataGrouped.length];

        int j=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataEntries.length; i+=3) {
            dataGrouped[j] = dataEntries[i];
            positions[j] = j;
            j++;                    
        }
        quickSort(dataGrouped,positions,0,dataGrouped.length-1);
        double[] merged = merge(dataEntries,positions);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(merged));
    }

    private static double[] merge(double[] dataEntries,int[] positions){
        double[] toReturn = new double[dataEntries.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            toReturn[i*3] = dataEntries[positions[i]*3];
            toReturn[i*3+1] = dataEntries[positions[i]*3+1];
            toReturn[i*3+2] = dataEntries[positions[i]*3+2];
        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    private static void quickSort(double[] array, int[] positions, int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

        int i = lowerIndex;
        int j = higherIndex;
        // calculate pivot number, I am taking pivot as middle index number
        double pivot = array[lowerIndex+(higherIndex-lowerIndex)/2];
        // Divide into two arrays
        while (i <= j) {
            /**
             * In each iteration, we will identify a number from left side which
             * is greater then the pivot value, and also we will identify a number
             * from right side which is less then the pivot value. Once the search
             * is done, then we exchange both numbers.
             */
            while (array[i] < pivot) {
                i++;
            }
            while (array[j] > pivot) {
                j--;
            }
            if (i <= j) {
                exchangeNumbers(array,positions, i, j);
                //move index to next position on both sides
                i++;
                j--;
            }
        }
        // call quickSort() method recursively
        if (lowerIndex < j)
            quickSort(array,positions, lowerIndex, j);
        if (i < higherIndex)
            quickSort(array,positions, i, higherIndex);
    }

    private static void exchangeNumbers(double[] array, int[] positions, int i, int j) {
        double temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;

        int postemp = positions[i];
        positions[i] = positions[j];
        positions[j] = postemp;
    }
}
```

Output is :

```
[1.0, 1.2, 1.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.1, 7.0, 7.1, 7.5]
```

Comment: Great answer, exactly what I wanted. If I could upvote twice I already would have.

Answer (score 2):

The safest and simplest way to do  this is to convert the array of doubles to a `List<SomeClass>`, where `SomeClass` is a class that holds 3 doubles and also implements `Comparable`.  You can then sort however you like, including using built-in sorting support, and then convert back to an array of doubles at the end.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution, do you also know a way which would require less objects?

Comment: That sounds a little bit like [premature optimisation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature).

Comment: I agree, it's a guilty pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Not considering the performance into note, O(n^2).  Assuming the array length is 3*n

```
 for(int i = 0;i<length_of_array-3;i+=3){
   for(int j = i+3; j<length_of_array-3;j+=3){
      if(arr[i] > arr[j]{
        swap(i,j);
    }
   }
```

you swap method would do

```
 swap(int i, int j){
  for(int k=i;k<i+3;k++,j++){
     double temp = arr[k]; 
     arr[k]=arr[j];
     arr[j]=temp;
   }
  }
```

Comment: I wonder which version is faster. The one with a lot of objects or n^2. Depends on the number of data-entries probably. Thanks!

Comment: If performance really matters, we could implement merge sort.  Its not really a challenge, just careful logi is suffice.  Say we have array of 12 elements (4 sets of data nt you case), instead of breaking it into sub arrays of 1, we do subraays of size 3