# Why do multiple processes slow down?

Tags: python, qt, io, hard-drive, child-process

Not sure this is the best title for this question but here goes.

Through python/Qt I started multiple processes of an executable. Each process is writing a large file (~20GB) to disk in chunks. I am finding that the first process to start is always the last to finish and continues on much, much longer than the other processes (despite having the same amount of data to write).

Performance monitors show that the process is still using the expected amount of RAM (~1GB), but the disk activity from the process has slowed to a trickle.

Why would this happen? It is as though the first process started somehow gets its' disk access 'blocked' by the other processes and then doesnt recover after the other processes have finished...

Would the OS (windows) be causing this? What can I do to alleviate this?

Comment: I'd look at the continuous write speed of your storage media, and compare the time to save that amount of data. hard drives can accept short bursts of data quickly due to their internal cache, but large files (sequential write) will take at least a certain minimum amount of time. I'm skeptical that one could ever get better write performance with multi-process writing to disk. It would seem to me that the overhead of multiple processes, and switching between file streams to write, performance would instead be much worse.

Answer (score 3):

**Parallelism (of any kind) only results in a speedup if you actually have the resources to solve the problem faster.**

[Before thinking of optimizing your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature), you should carefully analyze what's causing it to run (subjectively) slow - the [bottleneck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck_%28software%29).

While I know nothing about what sort bottleneck your program has, the fact that it writes a large quantity of data to disk is a good hint that it may be [I/O bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound).

When a program is I/O bound, the conventional single-machine parallelization techniques (threading, multiple processes) are *worse than useless* - they actually hurt performance, especially if you're dealing with a spinning disk. This happens because once you have more than one process accessing the disk at different places, the hard drive head has to [seek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seek_time#Seek_time) between those.

The [I/O scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_scheduling) of your OS can have a great impact on how slower performance becomes once you have multiple processes accessing I/O, and how processes are alloted disk accesses. You may consider switching your OS, but only if those multiple processes are *needed* in the first place.

---

With that being said, what *can* you do to get better (I/O) performance?

- Get better disks (or a SSD)
- Get more disks (one per process)
- Get more machines

Answer (score 0):

There are no guarantees as to fairness of I/O scheduling. What you're describing seems rather simple: the I/O scheduler, whether intentionally or not, gives a boost to new processes. Since your disk is tapped out, the order in which the processes finish is not under your control. You're most likely wasting a lot of disk bandwidth on seeks, due to parallel access from multiple processes.

TL;DR: Your expectation is unfounded. When I/O, and specifically the virtual memory system, is saturated, anything can happen. And so it does.