# How to extract href attribute from link and create a specific pattern of that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I explain my question with two examples:

**Example1:**

current string:

```
var str = 'anything <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">untitled</a> anything';
//                                                               ^ link-name
```

I want this string:

```
var newstr = 'anything www.google.com anything';
```

---

**Example2:**

Current string:

```
var str = 'anything <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">any thing else</a> anything';
//                                                                  ^ link-name
```

I want this string:

```
var str = 'anything [any thing else](www.google.com) anything';
```

---

As you see in the two examples above, `untitled` is a keyword. I want if link-name is `untitled`, then create a regular URL of that, but if it isn't, then create a pattern-based URL of that.

**Note:** pattern = `[LinkName](LinkAddress)`

How can I do that?

---

Also here is what I have tried:

```
var newStr = $('<div/>', {html: str}).find("a").replaceWith(function(){
  return $(this).attr('href'); // this.href would give absolute path
}).end().text();
```

My code creates a regular URL from all kind of links. How can I add that condition *(checking the link-name for being `untitled` or not)* to that?

Comment: input string is always in that short form? I think it's not and that is important thing to know. You want to parse whole html document to do this?

Comment: @RafałŁużyński Yes and no ...!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand. What you have done is right. Here are your solutions working perfectly fine:

```js
$(function () {
  var str = 'anything <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">untitled</a> anything';
  var newStr = $('<div/>', {html: str}).find("a").replaceWith(function(){
    return ($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() == 'untitled') ? $(this).attr('href') : "[" + $(this).text() + "](" + $(this).attr('href') + ")";
  }).end().text();
  $("body").append(newStr + "<br /><br />");
  str = 'anything <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">any thing else</a> anything';
  newStr = $('<div/>', {html: str}).find("a").replaceWith(function(){
    return ($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() == 'untitled') ? $(this).attr('href') : "[" + $(this).text() + "](" + $(this).attr('href') + ")";
  }).end().text();
  $("body").append(newStr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Updated Code (better version)**

```js
$(function () {
  var str = 'anything <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">untitled</a> anything';
  var newStr = string_it(str);
  $("body").append(newStr + "<br /><br />");
  str = 'anything <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">any thing else</a> anything';
  newStr = string_it(str);
  $("body").append(newStr);
});

function string_it (str) {
  return $('<div/>', {html: str}).find("a").replaceWith(function(){
    return ($(this).text().trim().toLowerCase() == 'untitled') ? $(this).attr('href') : "[" + $(this).text() + "](" + $(this).attr('href') + ")";
  }).end().text();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry. Because your answer isn't a solution. It is a workaround. You have implemented my two examples as static ..! But I need to a dynamic code which investigates the value of link-name *(being `untitled` keyword or not)* for every string.

Comment: @Shafizadeh Can you explain further please? I am interested in solving it.

Comment: I want something like this: `if (linkname == 'untitled') {// regular URL} else {// patter-based URL}`

Comment: @Shafizadeh Updated. Kindly look at the above code. `:)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98696/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-shafizadeh).

Comment: Seems good. But I don't know why doesn't work in my real codes. Anyway ok thanks. I accept your solution as my answer and if I faced with a question about it I will ask you later `:-)`

Comment: @Shafizadeh Share the full code, let me see if I can fix.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check the text content of the element:

```
var newStr = $('<div/>', {
  html: str
}).find("a").replaceWith(function() {
  var
    href = this.getAttribute('href'),
    text = this.textContent
  ;

  return text === 'untitled' 
         ? href 
         : "[" + text + "](" + href + ")";

}).end().text();
```

Comment: Oh one thing else, as a consult: I wat to use  of this [js-library](https://github.com/jgm/commonmark.js). Now I'm use it in my code like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vhd8qy6k/2/). What I want to know is, my codes are fine? defining a object in the function is optimized? or I can do that better? *(beforehand) thanks.

Comment: @Shafizadeh You are welcome. There is nothing wrong with your code and it's performance is fine for me. However, you can also initialize the instances outside of the function. https://jsfiddle.net/vhd8qy6k/4/. And here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature