# JavaScript Performance (typeof arr[i] === "undefined" || num < arr[i])

Tags: javascript, performance, micro-optimization

I'm looking for a way to avoid the `typeof` check on every `arr[i]`

I need to accommodate the fact that `arr[i]` can be `0`

I want to assign `arr[i] = num` if `arr[i]` is `undefined` or greater than `num`

Comment: Why would it be `undefined` in the first place? Doesn't seem like a useful value to have in an Array of numbers. Either way, there's no need for `typeof` to check for `undefined`.

Comment: How about this: `arr[i] = Math.max(arr[i] || 0, num)`

Comment: Why would you need to make such simple logic faster in the first place? It ain't gonna get much faster than that. You can try something like `if(!(num >= arr[i])){arr[i]=num;}` though to invert what happens for the case of it being undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The way to answer performance questions is to run benchmarks.

There are four alternatives:

1. `arr[i] === undefined || num < arr[i]`
2. `typeof arr[i] === 'undefined' || num < arr[i]`
3. `!(i in arr) || num < arr[i]`. This assumes the `undefined` values are true "holes" (missing indexes), rather than indexes that are present but have a value of `undefined`.
4. `!(num >= arr[i])`. This takes advantage of the fact that comparisons with `undefined` return `false`.

1 and 2 are equivalent performance-wise. 3 is about 20 times slower. 4 is about 20% slower. Using `isNaN` as suggested in another answer is about 50% slower.

Therefore, if you are interested purely in performance, use 1 or 2. If you want to save keystrokes, at a minor performance cost, use 4. However, 4 is also less readable and you probably will have to add a comment about how it handles `undefined`, which will negate any keystroke savings.

See http://jsperf.com/ways-to-check-for-undefined/4.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
arr[i] == undefined || num < arr[i]
```

or

```
arr[i]=(arr[i] >= 0 && arr [i] < num) ? arr[i] : num;
```

Or

```
arr[i]=(!isNaN(arr[i]) && arr [i] < num) ? arr[i] : num;
```

Comment: This will replace negative values of `arr[i]` with `num`, which probably is not what the OP intended.

Comment: For this case you can try with isNaN method

Comment: `isNaN` seems to be about 50% slower than a direct check for `undefined`. See http://jsperf.com/ways-to-check-for-undefined/5.

Comment: Oh thanks for update.. For this case, Your 1st option is cool but my suggetion is not to check type `arr[i] == undefined || num < arr[i]`

Answer (score 1):

Checking `something === something_else` is as fast as it gets, but what does make your code slower is the fact that you are doing two things instead of one:

You are checking both `typeof arr[i] === “undefined”` and `num < arr[i]` even though **javascript engine is going to check data type anyway**.

What I mean is, if it is true that `typeof arr[i] === “undefined”`, then `num < arr[i]` will always be false. It would also be false for `>=`, which leads to the solution.

Instead of:

```
if (typeof arr[i] === “undefined” || num < arr[i])
```

You can do:

```
if (!(num >= arr[i]))
```

#### On the other hand...

- if you don't **know** that it is currently too slow, which you don't if you did not profile it, then you should not optimize it. See: [When is optimisation premature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature)
- why do you even have undefined data in the list to begin with? Couldn't you filter that out before writing into the list, rather than at reading time? It is a good idea to always have only one data type in a contaioner (unless you have a really good reason otherwise)
- if you have a key->value mapping with some keys not defined, maybe Array is not the right container for your use case