# How can I filter array of state in react?

Tags: reactjs, filter, redux

I have order reducer, which has many states.

```
const initialState = {
 channel: null,
 order: {},
 fetching:true,
 menu: [],
 categories: [],
 subcategories: [],
 currentCategoryId: 1,
 currentSubcategoryId: 5,
 currentMenu: [],
};
```

What I want to filter is `menu`. `menu` is array of state which has objects of `menu_item` I have `currentCategoryId` and `currentSubcategoryId`. What I want to do with these states is that by using `currentCategoryId` and `currentSubcategoryId` to filter `menu` and put filtered states to `currentMenu`.

```
case Constants.ORDER_CHANNEL_CONNECTED:
 return
  {...state,currentMenu: action.menu.map((menu) => {
                    if(state.currentCategoryId == menu.category_id){
                        return menu;
                    }
                    else return false;}}
```

So to do that I made code like above. Even though it returns some filtered value, it shows same number of array with many false values. I want to find other approaches to do that..

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please use the `filter` function:

```
{...state,currentMenu: action.menu.filter((menu) =>
state.currentCategoryId == menu.category_id)}
```

P.S: I agree with the below answer, it's better to use Immutable.js

Comment: why do you think that it is better to use Immutable.js?? any benefits compare to use just `filter` function?

Comment: Main reason to use immutable is to avoid expensive cloning whole object. Immutable object store only difference to the previous version. It works faster especially in the large project with big state objects. You can read more about benefits [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227832/advantages-of-using-immutable-js-over-object-assign-or-spread-operators)

Answer (score 3):

I would say you can use immutable.js for this purpose. You can add `filter` to your map.

You can try something like

```
Immutable.map(state.menu).filter(state.currentCategoryId===menu.category_id)
```

P.S: I have not tested the above code but it should work with little modifications.

You can check out more about immutable [here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: thanks, I tried `currentMenu: Immutable.map(state.menu).filter(state.currentCategoryId===menu.category_id)`, but it triggers error that `Immutable.map is not defined`.. so I tried `Immutable.Map(state.menu)....` but it still triggers error that `menu is not defined` How should I change this?

Answer (score 2):

```
onTodoClick(id){
      this.setState({items: this.state.items.filter(item => item.news_id == id )
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are filtering by ID and it is numeric watch out for comparing strings and numbers.  I had to use parseInt (as below).

```
Arr.filter(single => parseInt(single.id) !== parseInt(id))
```

Consider this if javascript filter array is not working