# How do I efficiently convert an Immutable.js List of Maps to an array of plain js objects for use in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

Consider the following code:

```
import { fromJS } from "immutable"

const initialState = fromJS({
    radiusFilters: [
        { label: "1mi", value: 1 },
        { label: "2mi", value: 2 },
        ...
     ],
     locationOptionFilters: [
        { label: "State", value: "STATE" },
        { label: "City", value: "CITY" },
        ...
      ]
 }
```

A third party library, `react-select`, maintains that props for the Select elements be passed in as an array of objects, so it makes sense to me that I convert the above structures to their plain javascript equivalents at some point. These are going to be large structures, and I want the shallow checking that runs automatically when using `react-redux` with functional components to run as quickly as possible (hence my insistence on using `Immutable`).

### Are there any expensive implications to using the following selector?

```
const radiusFilterSelector = (state) => state.searchFilters.get("radiusFilters")

export const getRadiusFilters = createSelector([ radiusFilterSelector ], 
    radiusFilters => {
        return radiusFilters.toJS()
     }
)
```

In the `mapStateToProps` function of my React container, I'll call the necessary selectors, which will look much like the above, to populate the props that are passed to the component.

Answer (score 2):

There is a performance hit from using `fromJS()` and `toJS()`.

If you are only interested in a shallow comparision you could set initial state with a `Map()` instead of `fromJS()` and use `toArray()` instead of `toJS()` when you need to convert it back for use with the library.

However I wouldn't worry about performance until you know it is causing a bottleneck. See [When is optimisation premature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385506/when-is-optimisation-premature)