# Are java.util.zip.Deflater & java.util.zip.Inflater classes thread safe

Tags: java, thread-safety, compression

In one of class, we are performing thousands of deflate format compression, decompression in concurrent threads.

Every compression/decompression is done by creating a new instance of Deflater & Inflater respectively.

I am unable to find any documentation if these classes are thread safe. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Why do you care? I mean other than curiosity? Have you observed a problem with creating a new one each time? If not, then don't do [premature optimization](http://stackoverflow.com/q/385506/5221149).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think `synchronized` is the reason why these classes are thread-safe, but I want you to think about it slowly and find an answer by yourself:

`java.util.zip.Deflater`:

> The deflater class **compresses** input with the deflate algorithm described in RFC 1951.  It has several compression levels and three different strategies described below.
>
> **This class is *not* thread safe**.  This is inherent in the API, *due to the split of deflate and setInput.*

Source code: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/zip/Deflater-source.html

**CONCLUSION:** since compression is a raw transformation for lessen character codes values and bytes. It is not a good idea to *edit* the chain of bytes which are being compressed simultaneously in different (or ambiguous) processes. The output may result corrupted!.

`java.util.zip.Inflater` :

> > Inflater is used to **decompress** data that has been compressed according  the "deflate" standard described in RFC 1950. The usage is
> >     as following.  First you have to set some input with
> >     `setInput()`, then inflate() it.  *If inflate doesn't inflate any bytes there may be three reasons:*
> >
> > - *needsInput() returns true* because the input buffer is empty. You have to provide more input with `setInput()`.
> >       NOTE:  needsInput() also returns true when, the stream is finished.
> > - needsDictionary() returns true, you have to provide a preset  dictionary with `setDictionary()`.
> > - finished() returns true, the inflater has finished.
> >
> > Once the first output byte is produced, a dictionary will not needed at a later stage.

Source code: http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/zip/Inflater-source.html

**CONCLUSION:** The fact that a big chunk of data is being *decompressed* means that we can take some input (tinier chunks), then apply some algorithm to output back the original data. In this case *thread-safety* is not obliged. Because the initial data for this class (the bytes not inflated) can remain isolated, regardless of the additional computation to be performed (call them: remove bytes, add characters, alter). After all, the big chunk of data is prepared to be decompressed as is.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at source code, you'll find that code is `synchronized`, making it thread-safe.

However, `synchronized` means that a single `Deflater`/`Inflator` instance can only perform one operation at a time, so although it's thread-safe, it's not multi-threaded, i.e. it becomes a bottleneck if multiple threads try to use it at the same time.

So, yes, it is thread-safe, but you shouldn't share instances across threads, because it'll reduce the performance benefit of running multiple threads.

Comment: yes I looked into code but seems like apart from synchronization, there seems to be shared state in class like byte[] buf ,ZStreamRef zsRef and so on. I am not sure if same inflator/deflator instance is used by multiple threads at same time will leads to no issue because of this shared state.