# Is it the fastest way for storing data into SQL Server?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I would like to know that is the following source code, the best solution for fast storing data into SQL Server?

The application may store multiple records into a SQL Server table each second (as an example, 50 records in about 5 seconds). I don't want to loose any inserts.

```vb
Dim connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("INSERT STATEMENT", connection)
connection.Open()
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param1", Param1))
command.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Param2", Param2))
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
command.Dispose()
connection.Close()
```

Comment: 50 records in about 5 seconds is [as close to nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/385506/11683) as it gets.

Comment: +1 @GSerg The code you have posted is simple, correct (once you add a `using` block for the SqlConnection), and entirely appropriate for the level of throughput required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not giving the parameters datatypes and sizes can slow things down. Check http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

I passed in a List(Of Employee) which assumes a Class called Employee with Properties call FirstName and LastName but any enumerable containing the values you want to enter should work.

Add the parameters once outside the loop. Open the connection once, just before the loop and change the values of the parameters inside the loop.

The Using blocks will close and dispose your database objects.

```
Private Sub AddEmplyees(empList As List(Of Employee))
    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("CONNECTION STRING")
        Using command As New SqlCommand("Insert Into Employess (FirstName, LastName) Values (@FirstName, @LastName);", connection)
            command.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)
            command.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)
            connection.Open()
            For Each e In empList
                command.Parameters("@FirstName").Value = e.FirstName
                command.Parameters("@LastName").Value = e.LastName
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

1. No, it isn't - faster `INSERT` operations can be had using `BULK INSERT` or `bcp` - however those are for high-throughput operations (e.g. when you want to insert millions of records) with a long set-up time.
2. While connection-pooling is enabled by default, you might as well loop over your records within an existing connection.
3. Your code doesn't wrap the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects in a `using` block (or whatever VB's equivalent is) - while this won't affect performance, it will make your program better able to handle database-related exceptions.
4. If you want to be even faster, [insert from a table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters).

Comment: When I click on the first 2 links from the link you provided, it says "The product, service, or technology mentioned in this content is no longer supported."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load multiple records really fast you want to use Bulk Insert. I have loaded 1-2000 rows per second using Bulk Insert.

Please see this in MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

You can use XML data type as a parameter and you can pass multiple records using root, parent and child nodes.

[Example](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/1391/stored-procedure-with-xml-as-input).

Comment: Personally, I'd use a table-valued parameter instead of XML if the client API supports it.

Comment: If you're going to include an example, do so in your answer, not as an off site resource

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters?view=sql-server-2017#limitations-of-table-valued-parameters

Answer (score -1):

For better performance I encourage you to create indexes for your tables in SQL Server. Indexes improve your operations.

Comment: Please explain how an *index* improves the performance of an `insert`

Comment: @Ali - again how does that improve insert speed? The typical use of an index is to improve lookup speed.

Comment: I am no DBA but I think indexes actual slow down inserts because the index must be updated along with the data.